# built up Views and works then something wierd happened when populating a field

Tags: views, theming

Not sure how I did it or how to fix it, I was doing some work and some how the path changed for where the pictures were being retrieved.

Ignore the `localhost` and the `testredhat` prefixes in the urls. I have two test environments and they are exactly the same. The curious part is the fact that the url was truncated... The path should be the `.../sites/default/files/teldir` but some reason it all of a sudden cut off to `..//teldir/`.

[image]

[image]

The exported View with the issue:

```
   $view = new view();
$view->name = 'sweetser_directory';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Sweetser Directory';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Sweetser Directory';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'mini';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '50';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'field_picture' => 'field_picture',
  'title' => 'title',
  'field_building' => 'field_building',
  'field_cost_center' => 'field_cost_center',
  'field_location' => 'field_location',
  'field_mailstop' => 'field_mailstop',
  'field_user_email' => 'field_user_email',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'field_picture' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 1,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_building' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_cost_center' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 1,
  ),
  'field_location' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 1,
  ),
  'field_mailstop' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 1,
  ),
  'field_user_email' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 1,
  ),
);
/* Field: Content: Picture */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['id'] = 'field_picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['table'] = 'field_data_field_picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['field'] = 'field_picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_picture']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => '',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Building */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['id'] = 'field_building';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['table'] = 'field_data_field_building';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['field'] = 'field_building';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['alter']['text'] = '<br />[field_building]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['alter']['path'] = 'about-sweetser/directory/building/[field_building]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['alter']['link_class'] = 'blue_link_directory';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_building']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Cost Center */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cost_center']['id'] = 'field_cost_center';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cost_center']['table'] = 'field_data_field_cost_center';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cost_center']['field'] = 'field_cost_center';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cost_center']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cost_center']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_cost_center']['alter']['text'] = '<br />[field_cost_center]';
/* Field: Content: Location */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['id'] = 'field_location';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['table'] = 'field_data_field_location';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['field'] = 'field_location';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['alter']['text'] = '<br />[field_location]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['alter']['path'] = 'about-sweetser/directory/location/[field_location]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_location']['alter']['link_class'] = 'blue_link_directory';
/* Field: Content: Mailstop */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['id'] = 'field_mailstop';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['table'] = 'field_data_field_mailstop';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['field'] = 'field_mailstop';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['alter']['text'] = '<br />Mailstop: [field_mailstop]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['alter']['path'] = 'about-sweetser/directory/mailstop/[field_mailstop]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['alter']['link_class'] = 'blue_link_directory';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_mailstop']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: User Email */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_user_email']['id'] = 'field_user_email';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_user_email']['table'] = 'field_data_field_user_email';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_user_email']['field'] = 'field_user_email';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_user_email']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_user_email']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_user_email']['alter']['text'] = '<br /><a class="blue_link_directory" href="mailto:[field_user_email]">[field_user_email]</a>';
/* Field: Content: Title / Position */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['id'] = 'field_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['table'] = 'field_data_field_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['field'] = 'field_title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['alter']['text'] = '<br />[field_title]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['alter']['path'] = 'about-sweetser/directory/title/[field_title]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['alter']['link_class'] = 'blue_link_directory';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Path */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['id'] = 'path';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['field'] = 'path';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['path']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['text'] = '<strong><a href="[path]">[title]</a></strong>
[field_title]
[field_building]
[field_location]
[field_mailstop]
[field_user_email]
';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['link_to_node'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Nickname */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_nickname']['id'] = 'field_nickname';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_nickname']['table'] = 'field_data_field_nickname';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_nickname']['field'] = 'field_nickname';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_nickname']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Other Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_other_name']['id'] = 'field_other_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_other_name']['table'] = 'field_data_field_other_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_other_name']['field'] = 'field_other_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_other_name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['title']['field'] = 'title';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Supervisor nid (field_supervisor_nid) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['id'] = 'field_supervisor_nid_value';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_supervisor_nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['field'] = 'field_supervisor_nid_value';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'telephone_directory_entry' => 'telephone_directory_entry',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Global: Combine fields filter */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['id'] = 'combine';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['field'] = 'combine';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'combine_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['label'] = 'Name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['operator'] = 'combine_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['identifier'] = 'combine';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['combine']['fields'] = array(
  'title' => 'title',
  'field_nickname' => 'field_nickname',
  'field_other_name' => 'field_other_name',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Phone Number (field_phone_number) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['id'] = 'field_phone_number_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_phone_number';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['field'] = 'field_phone_number_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['operator'] = 'contains';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'field_phone_number_value_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['expose']['label'] = 'Reverse Phone Number';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['expose']['operator'] = 'field_phone_number_value_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['expose']['identifier'] = 'field_phone_number_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_phone_number_value']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['id'] = 'title_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['operator'] = '!=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['group'] = 1;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'about-sweetser/directory';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Staff Directory';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Sweetser Directory - Employees without Photos';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'telephone_directory_entry' => 'telephone_directory_entry',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['operator'] = 'allwords';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['label'] = 'Name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['operator'] = 'title_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['identifier'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title']['expose']['remember_roles'] = array(
  2 => '2',
  1 => 0,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Employee ID (field_employee_id) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_employee_id_value']['id'] = 'field_employee_id_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_employee_id_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_employee_id';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_employee_id_value']['field'] = 'field_employee_id_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_employee_id_value']['operator'] = 'not empty';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Picture (field_picture:fid) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_picture_fid']['id'] = 'field_picture_fid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_picture_fid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_picture';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_picture_fid']['field'] = 'field_picture_fid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_picture_fid']['operator'] = 'empty';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'about-sweetser/directory/no-photos';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'normal';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Staff Directory';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Supervisees';
$handler->display->display_options['display_description'] = 'When you are viewing a user\'s profile this block will show their supervisees';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: Content: Supervisor nid (field_supervisor_nid) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['id'] = 'field_supervisor_nid_value';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_supervisor_nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['field'] = 'field_supervisor_nid_value';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['default_argument_type'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['field_supervisor_nid_value']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'telephone_directory_entry' => 'telephone_directory_entry',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['id'] = 'title_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['operator'] = '!=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['title_1']['group'] = 1;
```

Comment: Please share your views code by exporting it, this would help us to identify the exact issue.

Comment: If it's working on localhost server, and not working on your testredhat server, this mean that you certainly forget some configurations in the second server (maybe the image field setting of your content type 'telephone_directory_entry'). if you'r not sure try to clone the first database to the second one

Comment: I exported the working View and imported it in the test. It still is giving me a problem. I will just have to blow out the test environment, I was just curious why or how it could happen.

Comment: `telephone_directory_entry` is in the testredhat environment. When I carried everything over it worked just fine, it's when I manipulated some files that I noticed the issue. I notice all Views that grab images are having an issue. I would say it's a permission issue, but as you can see that is a url that has been cut up.